# Change color on tap in a Flutter application

Tags: flutter

I am trying to change the color of card on tap which was created by ListView.Builder. I tried with Inkwell and wrapping the `listview` inside container.

Now problem is if I click or tap on any list item all cards color get changed. I need to change the color of card which I am tapping not on all.

In simple words, if user tap on item I want to show it selected like we have seen in other apps.

Below is the code.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Theme(
      isMaterialAppTheme: true,
      data: ThemeData(
      ),

     child:Scaffold(
       key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: myAppBar(),
      endDrawer: myDrawer(),
        body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,


          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color:Colors.grey,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(4.0))),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:16.0, vertical: 15.0),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text("Booking Details",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                letterSpacing: 3,
                wordSpacing: 3
              ),)),


            Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              itemCount: lists.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                return Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color:Colors.grey,
                     ),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:15, right: 15.0, bottom: 10.0),
                      child: Material(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        child:InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                                _color = !_color;
                            });
                          },
                         child: Container(
                               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                 color: _color ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.purpleAccent,
                              ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                               
                               Expanded(
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                     Text('Class From -: ' + lists[index].title+ ',
                                     style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                    ),),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                                    Text('Subject -: ' + lists[index].product,
                                     style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                      
                                    ),),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                                    Text('Price -: ' + lists[index].price.toString() + ' USD  ' + lists[index].serviceType,
                                     style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                    ),),
                                    SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                                   
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                     ],
                );
              },

            ),),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color:Colors.black12,
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Subtotal      \$50", style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    fontSize: 16.0
                  ),),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                  Text("Delivery       \$05", style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    fontSize: 16.0
                  ),),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                  Text("Cart Subtotal     \$55", style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18.0
                  ),),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      height: 50.0,
                      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                      child: Text("Secure Checkout".toUpperCase(), style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white
                      ),),
                      onPressed: (){},
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: //Define index here
int _selectedIndex = -1;

//then update index
setState(() {
                                _selectedIndex = index;
                            });

//and update color logic
color: index ==_selectedIndex ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.purpleAccent,

Comment: @Gaurav Thanks for the comment. Can you give me some example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Define index  with default value of -1

```
int _selectedIndex = -1;
```

Step 2: Update index on click of list item

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        if(_selectedIndex == index){
          _selectedIndex= -1;
         }else{
         _selectedIndex= index;
        }
      });
    },
```

Step 3: Update your item  color logic

```
 decoration: BoxDecoration(color: index== _selectedIndex  ? 
                                  Colors.deepOrangeAccent : 
                                  Colors.purpleAccent,),
```

Comment: just one thing i want. If i tap again then how can i change the color. At the moment selected item is not getting unselect.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bool field in your object class instead of the _color variable, in my case I have created a Booking class with the following fields for testing:

```
class Booking {
    String title;
    String subject;
    int price;
    bool selected;
    Booking({this.title, this.subject, this.price, this.selected});
}
// list example
List<Booking> lists = [
    Booking(title: "Title", subject: "Subject", price: 10, selected: false),
    Booking(title: "Title", subject: "Subject", price: 10, selected: false),
    Booking(title: "Title", subject: "Subject", price: 10, selected: false),
    Booking(title: "Title", subject: "Subject", price: 10, selected: false),
    Booking(title: "Title", subject: "Subject", price: 10, selected: false)
];
```

In your Inkwell ontap, control the selected variable like this:

```
onTap: () {
    setState(() {
         lists[index].selected = !lists[index].selected;
    });
```

},

In your Inkwell boxdecoration, change it to this so that it checks whether the individual object is selected:

```
child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: lists[index].selected ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.purpleAccent,
),
```

It works on dartpad.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9QLt.png)

Comment: Hello there Nickypangers,
Your code here looks really great, could you paste this whole code  here?

Comment: @Jan HI I dont have my original code but I made a new one just now based on the answer I wrote: https://dartpad.dev/0017f137e73a196c6b2ee400d2e31642?

Answer (score 1):

Once I tried this approach. Just try it.

Define a global boolean array 'isSelect'. Boolean for each card item.

```
List<bool> isSelect = [false, false, false, false, false, false];
```

Toggle the boolean value when Inkwell widget ontap().
Set the colour of card on if condition based on the boolean value isSelect.

```
    return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        isSelect.setAll(0, [false, false, false, false, false, false]);
        isSelect[ItemID] = !isSelect[ItemID];
      });
      //print("selected " + selectedName);
    },
    child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: isSelect[ItemID] ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)
        ),
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        child: Column(
          ...

        )));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer George. My cards are generated from database. Numbers can vary. I didn't understand why you are defining this. isSelect.setAll(0, [false, false, false, false, false, false]);

Comment: in my case only one item is selected at once.
I used it to change other items to deselect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isPressed = !isPressed;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  color: isPressed ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isPressed = !isPressed;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  color: isPressed ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              ChangeColor(
                isPressed: isPressed,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              ChangeColor(),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChangeColor extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChangeColor({
    Key key,
    this.isPressed = false,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final bool isPressed;

  @override
  _ChangeColorState createState() => _ChangeColorState();
}

class _ChangeColorState extends State<ChangeColor> {
  bool _isPressed;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isPressed = widget.isPressed;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _isPressed = !_isPressed;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        color: _isPressed ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap you Card widget on StatefulWidget widget.
- Pass you Card widget as child.
- add "color" property and copy others.
- return new Card widget from build method().

like this:

```
SelectableCard(
  card: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
    child: const Text('UI/UX')),
)
```

```
class SelectableCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Card card;

  const SelectableCard({Key? key, required this.card}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SelectableCardState createState() => _SelectableCardState();
}

class _SelectableCardState extends State<SelectableCard> {
  bool isSelect = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          isSelect = !isSelect;
        });
      },
      child: Card(
        color: isSelect ? Colors.grey : widget.card.color,
        shape: widget.card.shape,
        child: widget.card.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```